# Programmatically adding TableRow to TableLayout not working

Tags: android, android-layout, tablelayout

I'm trying to add table rows programmatically following the code [here](http://en.androidwiki.com/wiki/Dynamically_adding_rows_to_TableLayout)

```
    /* Find Tablelayout defined in main.xml */
    TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.SaleOrderLines);
    /* Create a new row to be added. */
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
    tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    /* Create a Button to be the row-content. */
    Button b = new Button(this);
    b.setText("Dynamic Button");
    b.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    /* Add Button to row. */
    tr.addView(b);
    /* Add row to TableLayout. */
    //tr.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sf_gradient_03);
    tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

But but nothing is drawn to the screen. (same as one mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200691/dynamically-add-tablerow-to-tablelayout))

When i added `tr.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sf_gradient_03);`, the row with the background image is drawn but not the button

Here is my Layout

```
<!-- Sale Order Lines START -->
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/SaleOrderLinesArea" android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:padding="10dip" android:background="@drawable/sf_gradient_11" >
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/subHeaderArea" android:padding="10dip"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <TextView android:id="@+id/screenTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/title_sub" android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="Order Lines" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TableLayout android:id="@+id/SaleOrderLines"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="10dip" android:stretchColumns="*">
        <TableRow
            android:background="@drawable/sf_gradient_13" android:padding="10dip"
            >
            <TextView android:id="@+id/order_ref_label"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/fg_prime" android:text="bLA bLA" />
            <TextView android:id="@+id/product_label"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="@color/fg_title"
                android:text="@string/product" />
            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="@color/fg_title"
                android:text="@string/product_quantity" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:background="@drawable/sf_gradient_03"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip" android:paddingRight="10dip"
            >
            <TextView android:id="@+id/order_ref_label"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/fg_prime" android:text="Fooo" />
            <Spinner android:id="@+id/product_spinner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:prompt="@string/customer_prompt">
            </Spinner>
            <EditText android:id="@+id/product_uom_qty"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:singleLine="true" android:fadingEdge="horizontal" /> 
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="5dip" android:paddingBottom="5dip">
        <Button android:id="@+id/add_button" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Add Lines" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<!-- Sale Order Lines END -->
```

Comment: Have you done tl.requestLayout();? after adding rows in it?

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Got it, every `LayoutParams` should be of `android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams` except one that supplied to `tl.addView(...)`

```
/* Find Tablelayout defined in main.xml */
TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.SaleOrderLines);
/* Create a new row to be added. */
TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
/* Create a Button to be the row-content. */
Button b = new Button(this);
b.setText("Dynamic Button");
b.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
/* Add Button to row. */
tr.addView(b);
/* Add row to TableLayout. */
//tr.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sf_gradient_03);
tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. But I don't understand "except one that supplied to tl.addView() " because you used it there as well

Comment: This seems like a lot of work to add a line to a grid.The new constructor is called 4 times.

Comment: @EricBarr that link redirects to spam now.

Comment: what if the tablerow is already containing several elements.... could'nt we just duplicate the tablerow directly into single variable and do something with the existings elemnts?

Answer (score 10):

Please do note that, may be your code is perfect but the classes you are using are not proper. You may have used `import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams` , where as the correct class is available from following import statement :

> import android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I changed the width from `TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT` to `TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT`, then it works.

```
TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```