# Table Rows created on the fly not showing up in the view

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Programatically adding TableRow to TableLayout not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279501/programatically-adding-tablerow-to-tablelayout-not-working)

Here the code:

```
DtoCbpOutcome[] outcomes = cbp.Outcomes;
Log.d(_logTag, "# of outcomes: " + Integer.toString(outcomes.length));
TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tbl_cbp_outcomes);
for (int i = 0; i < outcomes.length; i++) {

    // Text Views:
    // public String Description;

    TableRow tr = new TableRow(appCtx);
    tr.setLayoutParams(tbl_lay_parms);

    // Row Count
    TextView row_num = new TextView(appCtx);
    temp_string = Integer.toString(i + 1);
    row_num.setText(temp_string);
    row_num.setLayoutParams(lay_parms);
    tr.addView(row_num);

    // Description
    TextView desc = new TextView(appCtx);
    temp_string = outcomes[i].Description;
    desc.setText(temp_string);
    desc.setLayoutParams(lay_parms);
    tr.addView(desc);

    tl.addView(tr, tbl_lay_parms);
}
```

From the layout file:

```
        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tbl_cbp_outcomes"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp" >
        </TableLayout>
```

I think this is the structure that I am building:

```
TableLayout (R.id.tbl_cbp_outcomes)
    TableRow (tr)
        TextView (row_num)
        TextView (desc)
```

But the row is not showing up in the layout view (activity_business_plan.xml).

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

**Update 1**

From the Log: *# of outcomes: 5* which is produced by `outcomes.length`

**Update 2**

The complete layout xml:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/green_nature_header"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="@string/label_project_relationships"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_cbp_rel_global_priorities"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="@string/double_dash" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_cbp_related_regional_priority_strategies"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="@string/double_dash" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_cbp_related_whole_system_priorities"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="@string/double_dash" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_cbp_related_demonstration_priorities"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="@string/double_dash" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/green_nature_header"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="@string/label_vision_statement"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_cbp_vision_statement"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="@string/double_dash" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/green_nature_header"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="@string/label_outcomes"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tbl_cbp_outcomes"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp" >
        </TableLayout>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/green_nature_header"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="@string/label_strategies"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tbl_cbp_strategies"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp" >
        </TableLayout>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/green_nature_header"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="@string/label_intermediate_results"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tbl_cbp_intermediate_results"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp" >
        </TableLayout>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/green_nature_header"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="@string/label_activities"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tbl_cbp_activities"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp" >
        </TableLayout>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/green_nature_header"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="@string/label_risks"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tbl_cbp_risks"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp" >
        </TableLayout>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/green_nature_header"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="@string/label_keywords"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_cbp_keywords"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="@string/double_dash" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_cbp_modified"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="@string/double_dash"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: This looks fine. Post the XML that holds your Table and what is `outcomes.length` (more than `0`)?

Comment: I've added the xml for the table. Also, outcomes.length produces 5. Which I manually checked to be the number of outcomes there are.

Comment: I would like to see the layout that holds the TableLayout as well.

Comment: @Saifuddin I checked that post but the results did not fix my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if is that but:

Are you using "TableLayout.LayoutParams" in  *tl.addView(tr, tbl_lay_parms);*

and a "TableRow.LayoutParams" in *tr.setLayoutParams(tbl_lay_parms);*

I think it is different, please check this http://en.androidwiki.com/wiki/Dynamically_adding_rows_to_TableLayout

Best regards