# Adding rows dynamically to the `TableLayout`

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I have a table,where the situation is it has to be popped up dynamically by taking the values from the database.I'm not sure about whether dynamically rows are extended,So please tell me ,whether it is possible or not.

Comment: refer to this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18207894/2987421

Comment: if number of entries are more then use list instead of table

Comment: yes. but I want a table like structure (two Columns) can this possible in ListView

Comment: TableRow child=new TableRow(getActivity());
  child.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
  child.addView(yourview);
  tableLayout.addView(child);

Comment: you can also use gridview

Comment: thanks for the valuable comments .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programatically adding TableRow to TableLayout not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279501/programatically-adding-tablerow-to-tablelayout-not-working)