# Android add row to table on button click

Tags: java, android

I have a TableLayout in my application. I have Two definite Rows so far. One Row has static items assigned to it, and the other has 3 spinners assigned top it.

What I'd like to do is, add a new TableRow when ever I click on a button. So far I have the following code:

```
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    android:stretchColumns="0,1,2"

    <Spinner
    android:padding="3dip"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:id="@+id/Spinner1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />


    <Spinner
    android:padding="3dip"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:id="@+id/Spinner2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

    <Spinner
    android:padding="3dip"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:id="@+id/spinner3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />
</TableRow>
```

This is just me second row, the row that I want to add when ever I click said button. MY question is, how do I add the following row into my view, every time the user clicks the button? The values of the spinners will differ, but the variables will stay the same.

Edit:

More code:

```
        /* Find Tablelayout defined in teh XML file */
    TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.listTable);
    /* Create a new row to be added. */
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
    tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    /* Create a Button to be the row-content. */
    Button b = new Button(this);
    b.setText("Add row");
    b.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    /* Add Button to row. */
    tr.addView(b);
    /* Add row to TableLayout. */

    tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}
```

View changed to this:

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/copyRow"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" >
    android:stretchColumns="0,1,2"

    <Spinner
    android:padding="3dip"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:id="@+id/Spinner1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />


    <Spinner
    android:padding="3dip"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:id="@+id/Spinner2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

    <Spinner
    android:padding="3dip"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:id="@+id/spinner3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />
</TableRow>
```

If It makes a difference, I'm using JellyBean 4.3 as the target API

Comment: why don't you use ListView with custom Adapter ?
btw you may find your solution here 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/7280804/855843

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't work at all. I'd prefer to just use the same row as the one above. When I click the button, absolutely nothing what so ever happens.

Comment: can you share your code where you try to add row ?

Comment: the attached code is not complete, but anyway there are few points you should know. 1) in code snippet you attached there is no appropriate part for button handling, so you are not adding new row in code given
2) when you define new row it is just a TableRow with empty content.
even though you can inflate it from your defined xml layout but this still wont work because whenever you add new row it will be exact the same row as one previously added because each time you will be referring to the same layout.

Comment: As I told you it is bad idea to have table layout and add rows dynamically. If you want I can add an answer to your question that uses Adapter and ListView.

Comment: Please add it. I'm still struggling to get the ListView and adapter to work, but it's proving rather hard.

Comment: I added it, please take a look and let me know

Comment: Thank, will do. Busy trying to implement the code into my instance right now.

Answer (score 0):

here is solution with ListView

you can finde all source code [here](http://ge.tt/12Zonrb1/v/0?c)

**Activity Class**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


private List<RowItem> rows = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
private ListView list;
private Button addButton;
private SimpleListAdapter listAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // get view elements
    list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    addButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addButton);


    //lets add few items to our list, note that selection item should not exceed length of spinners item
    rows.add(new RowItem(0, 0, 0));
    rows.add(new RowItem(0, 1, 2));
    rows.add(new RowItem(2, 1, 1));

    //create adapter and assign it to your list view

    listAdapter = new SimpleListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, rows);
    list.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    addButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            rows.add(new RowItem(0, 0, 0));
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

**Adapter Class**

```
public class SimpleListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem>{

private Context context;
private int layoutResourceId;   
private List<RowItem> data = null;

private ArrayList<String> spinnerArray1 = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> spinnerArray2 = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> spinnerArray3 = new ArrayList<String>();

public SimpleListAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<RowItem> data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;

    spinnerArray1.add("S1 One");
    spinnerArray1.add("S1 Two");
    spinnerArray1.add("S1 Three");

    spinnerArray2.add("S2 One");
    spinnerArray2.add("S2 Two");
    spinnerArray2.add("S2 Three");

    spinnerArray3.add("S3 One");
    spinnerArray3.add("S3 Two");
    spinnerArray3.add("S3 Three");
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ItemHolder holder;
    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new ItemHolder();
        holder.Spinner1 = (Spinner)row.findViewById(R.id.Spinner1);
        holder.Spinner2 = (Spinner)row.findViewById(R.id.Spinner2);
        holder.Spinner3 = (Spinner)row.findViewById(R.id.Spinner3);


        //add adapter to spinners so that there is something to select from
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray1);
        holder.Spinner1.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter1);

        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray2);
        holder.Spinner2.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter2);

        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray3);
        holder.Spinner3.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter3);

        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ItemHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    final RowItem rowItem = data.get(position);
    holder.Spinner1.setSelection(rowItem.getSelectionIndex1());
    holder.Spinner2.setSelection(rowItem.getSelectionIndex2());
    holder.Spinner3.setSelection(rowItem.getSelectionIndex3());

    holder.Spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "you selected an item from spinner 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    return row;
}


class ItemHolder{
    Spinner Spinner1;
    Spinner Spinner2;
    Spinner Spinner3;
}
```

**simple model**

```
public class RowItem {

private int selectionIndex1;
private int selectionIndex2;
private int selectionIndex3;


public RowItem(int selectionIndex1, int selectionIndex2, int selectionIndex3) {
    super();
    this.selectionIndex1 = selectionIndex1;
    this.selectionIndex2 = selectionIndex2;
    this.selectionIndex3 = selectionIndex3;
}
public int getSelectionIndex1() {
    return selectionIndex1;
}
public void setSelectionIndex1(int selectionIndex1) {
    this.selectionIndex1 = selectionIndex1;
}
public int getSelectionIndex2() {
    return selectionIndex2;
}
public void setSelectionIndex2(int selectionIndex2) {
    this.selectionIndex2 = selectionIndex2;
}
public int getSelectionIndex3() {
    return selectionIndex3;
}
public void setSelectionIndex3(int selectionIndex3) {
    this.selectionIndex3 = selectionIndex3;
}
```

}

**View items: Main view**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center" >

<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:dividerHeight="5dp"/>

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/addButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Add Item"
    />
```

**item renderer for list view**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/Spinner1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:padding="3dip" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/Spinner2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:padding="3dip" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/Spinner3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:padding="3dip" />
```