# Why does nothing appear when adding TableRow to TableLayout from code

Tags: android, android-layout

I am creating the TableLayout in XML:

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/button_area"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_weight="3">
```

And then I try to add buttons to rows (to replicate the effect of a "wrap panel" - a little surprised Android doesn't have this, but nevermind):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TableLayout layout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.button_area);

    TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
    row.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    for (int i = 0; i != 12; i++) {
        Button b = new Button(this);
        b.setText("something");
        b.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        row.addView(b);

        if (i + 1 % 4 == 0) {
            layout.addView(row);
            row = new TableRow(this);
        }
    }
}
```

The result is nothing - no null pointer exceptions, no failures to any of the logs, but unfortunately no buttons visible in the TableLayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After randomly changing stuff it turns out that I needed to remove this line:

```
b.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

I don't know why buttons cannot have layout params set if they are being put into a tablerow, I don't know why Android has this mess of identically named LayoutParams classes and if you use the wrong one then stuff silently fails, but this was my problem.

You would have thought that people willing to rename FILL_PARENT to MATCH_PARENT because they thought it would be easier to understand would not have this sort of silent-fail multi-choice class system.

Answer (score 0):

The statements inside this if clause will never be executed.

```
    if (i + 1 % 4 == 0) {
        layout.addView(row);
        row = new TableRow(this);
    }
```

That is why.

remove the if and let buttons be added freely without a condition, and they will show up, then check the fault in your if condition: i + 1 % 4 == 0

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you have imported LayoutParams of TableLayout and not those of ViewGroup. Many similar questions have already been answered on StackOverflow like this one: [Programmatically adding TableRow to TableLayout not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279501/programatically-adding-tablerow-to-tablelayout-not-working)

Comment: Thanks, I worked it out myself before your post. Basically I found that Buttons cannot have layout params if programmatically inserted into a TableRow. I've documented it in my answer.