# How to generate android linear layout by code in scroll view?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a scroll view and a list.I created my own list and did not using the list view that comes with android API.
I need to generate this list dynamically by web service.
This is my list:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="ir.tehraninternet780.standupcomedy.Main3Activity"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView14"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/selectmatchtext"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView14"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:background="@drawable/multi_bg2"
            android:id="@+id/RelativeBtn1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView14"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView9"
                android:src="@drawable/masoodi"
                android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView10"
                android:src="@drawable/logo780old"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="علی مسعودی"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView9"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView9"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView9"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView9"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView9"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/White" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="شقایق دهقان"
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView10"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView10"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView10"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView10"
                android:textColor="@color/White" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:background="@drawable/multi_bg2"
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_below="@+id/RelativeBtn1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView15"
                android:src="@drawable/masoodi"
                android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView16"
                android:src="@drawable/dehghan"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="علی مسعودی"
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView15"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView15"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView15"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView15"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView15"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/White" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="شقایق دهقان"
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView16"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView16"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView16"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView16"
                android:textColor="@color/White" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:background="@drawable/multi_bg2"
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView19"
                android:src="@drawable/masoodi"
                android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView20"
                android:src="@drawable/dehghan"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="علی مسعودی"
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView19"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView19"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView19"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView19"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView19"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/White" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="شقایق دهقان"
                android:id="@+id/textView10"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView20"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView20"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView20"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView20"
                android:textColor="@color/White" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:background="@drawable/multi_bg2"
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView23"
                android:src="@drawable/masoodi"
                android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView24"
                android:src="@drawable/dehghan"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="علی مسعودی"
                android:id="@+id/textView13"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView23"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView23"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView23"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView23"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView23"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/White" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="شقایق دهقان"
                android:id="@+id/textView14"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView13"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView24"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView24"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView24"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView24"
                android:textColor="@color/White" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:background="@drawable/multi_bg2"
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout4"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView21"
                android:src="@drawable/masoodi"
                android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView22"
                android:src="@drawable/dehghan"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="علی مسعودی"
                android:id="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView21"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView21"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView21"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView21"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView21"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/White" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="شقایق دهقان"
                android:id="@+id/textView12"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView22"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView22"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView22"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView22"
                android:textColor="@color/White" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:background="@drawable/multi_bg2"
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView17"
                android:src="@drawable/masoodi"
                android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView18"
                android:src="@drawable/dehghan"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="علی مسعودی"
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView17"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView17"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView17"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView17"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView17"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/White" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="شقایق دهقان"
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView18"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView18"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView18"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView18"
                android:textColor="@color/White" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

how can i generate pink ones in code and put them in scroll view???
[image]

Comment: The one who vote -1 am I asking a joke???

Comment: `I have a scroll view and a list` Why not a **ListView**? By the way, try your best to flatten your layouts.

Comment: Because I want to have two pictures in each row of the list and that's impossible!

Comment: What? Impossible? Have you ever heard of **custom** ListView Items?

Comment: Not optimized, but good enough to demonstrate i's really possible: http://custom-android-dn.blogspot.it/2013/01/listviewis-view-group-that-displays.html

Comment: By the way, you **don't need** to use ImageViews at all, since you can incorporate **compound drawables** inside the TextViews. Which also helps you flattening your layout design.

Answer (score 1):

I agreee with Frank. A listview would be best but you can do something similar to this:
[Programmatically adding TableRow to TableLayout not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279501/programatically-adding-tablerow-to-tablelayout-not-working)

```
ScrollView yourScroll = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.yourScroll);

LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(this);

l.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
//l.setBackground(Color.parseColor("#"));
yourScroll.addView(l);
```

This would add a linear layout as a child. Add horizontal orientation by saying something like (before add to scrollview:

```
l.setOrientation(...
```

Custom adapter with listview example: https://github.com/kweaver00/android-learning/tree/master/ListView