# Android TableLayout Exception while adding row at runtime

Tags: java, android, android-tablelayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tbl_att_summary"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1"
    android:shrinkColumns="1">
    <TableRow android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:text="Class"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Subject"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Time Period"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Work Days"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/header_row_att_summary">
        <!-- first column for Class - Section -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:id="@+id/txt_class_sec_att_summary"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" />
        <!-- Second column for subject -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:id="@+id/txt_subjec_att_summary"
            android:text="Chemistry"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />
        <!-- third column for duration (time period) for the attendance -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_time_period_att_summary"
            android:text="Feb-15"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal|end"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
        <!-- fourth column for the total number of working days -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_working_days_att_summary"
            android:text="18"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal|end"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
    </TableRow>
    <View
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#FF909090"/>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
        <TextView
            android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Roll No"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TextView
            android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Days Present"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TextView
            android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Percentage"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/row_att_detail"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_roll_no"
            android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_student_name"
            android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_days_present"
            android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_percentage"
            android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"/>

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Corresponding java code

```
public class ShowAttendanceSummary extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_attendance_summary);

            // set up the header rows
            TableRow header_row = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.header_row_att_summary);
            ((TextView) header_row.findViewById(R.id.txt_class_sec_att_summary)).
                    setText((getIntent().getStringExtra("class") + "-" +
                            getIntent().getStringExtra("section")));
            ((TextView) header_row.findViewById(R.id.txt_subjec_att_summary)).
                    setText((getIntent().getStringExtra("subject")));

            // showing month/year is slightly tricky. As we are passing strings like "current year",
            // "last year", or "till date", we need get the year value
            Integer yr = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
            System.out.print("year=" + Integer.toString(yr));
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Integer.toString(yr), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            switch (getIntent().getStringExtra("year")) {
                case "current_year":
                    ((TextView) header_row.findViewById(R.id.txt_time_period_att_summary)).
                            setText((getIntent().getStringExtra("month") + "-" +
                                    Integer.toString(yr)));
                    break;
                case "last_year":
                    ((TextView) header_row.findViewById(R.id.txt_time_period_att_summary)).
                            setText((getIntent().getStringExtra("month") + "-" +
                                    Integer.toString(yr - 1)));
                    break;
                case "till_date":
                    ((TextView) header_row.findViewById(R.id.txt_time_period_att_summary)).
                            setText("Till Date");
                    break;
            }

            final TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tbl_att_summary);
            final ArrayList<TableRow> tableRows = new ArrayList<>();

            // get the list of students
            String tag = "AttendanceListSummary";
            final String student_list_url = "http://" +
                    MiscFunctions.getInstance().getServerIP(getApplicationContext())
                    + "/student/list/" +
                    getIntent().getStringExtra("class") + "/" +
                    getIntent().getStringExtra("section") + "/?format=json";
            JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest
                    (Request.Method.GET, student_list_url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++)
                                try {
                                    JSONObject jo = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                    // get the name of the student. We need to join first and last names
                                    String f_name = jo.getString("fist_name");
                                    String l_name = jo.getString("last_name");
                                    String full_name = f_name + " " + l_name;

                                    // get the roll number of the student
                                    String roll_no = jo.getString("roll_number");
                                    TableRow detail_row = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.row_att_detail);
                                    ((TextView) detail_row.findViewById(R.id.txt_roll_no)).
                                            setText(roll_no);
                                    ((TextView) detail_row.findViewById(R.id.txt_student_name)).
                                            setText(full_name);
                                    tableRows.add(detail_row);
                                    tableLayout.addView(tableRows.get(i));

                                } catch (JSONException je) {
                                    System.out.println("Ran into JSON exception " +
                                            "while trying to fetch the list of students");
                                    je.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    System.out.println("Caught General exception " +
                                            "while trying to fetch the list of students");
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            System.out.println("inside volley error handler");
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        }
                    });

            com.classup.AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest, tag);

            JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
            try {
                params.put("class", getIntent().getStringExtra("class"));
                params.put("section", getIntent().getStringExtra("section"));
                params.put("subject", getIntent().getStringExtra("subject"));
                params.put("month", getIntent().getStringExtra("month"));
                params.put("year", getIntent().getStringExtra("year"));
            } catch (JSONException je) {
                System.out.println("unable to create json for selected subjects");
                je.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

As it can be seen that I am trying to add rows to my `TableLayout` at runtime. However, I get the following exception:

> classup W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified
>   child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's
>   parent first.

Can somebody have a look and suggest what mistake I am making here.

Answer (score 0):

The exception you've got likely pertains to this block of your codes.

```
try {
    JSONObject jo = response.getJSONObject(i);
    // get the name of the student. We need to join first and last names
    String f_name = jo.getString("fist_name");
    String l_name = jo.getString("last_name");
    String full_name = f_name + " " + l_name;

    // get the roll number of the student
    String roll_no = jo.getString("roll_number");
    TableRow detail_row = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.row_att_detail);
    ((TextView) detail_row.findViewById(R.id.txt_roll_no)).setText(roll_no);
    ((TextView) detail_row.findViewById(R.id.txt_student_name)).
                                        setText(full_name);
    tableRows.add(detail_row);
    tableLayout.addView(tableRows.get(i));
}
```

Some notes that you should beware of:

- Views can only be attached to the main view hierarchy only once. Thus, if you attempt to attach an already-attached view to the hierarchy again, you will get an exception.
- If you add a child to a `TableRow`, you then don't need to add that `TableRow` to the main `TableLayout` again.

Comment: Fine, but how can I make a new instance of tablerow with id row_att_detail in the try.. catch block above?

Comment: @Atulgupta For getting a new instance, you should instantiate a new `TableRow` by keyword `new` not `findViewById`.

Comment: @Atulgupta http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279501/programatically-adding-tablerow-to-tablelayout-not-working