# Data positioning in a TableLayout - Android Studio

Tags: android, string, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I have two activities (A and B), activity A asks for a text input (string) and activity B stores that string in a table. What I wish to achieve: every time I add a new string into the table, the previous string moves down one row and the new string takes the old string's place. I also wish to save the table layout in activity B every time I return to activity A. How would I go about achieving this ?

Comment: How about a RecyclerView that inserts at the beginning of the adapter? You have dynamic data, so best to use an adapter

Comment: Thanks for your reply @cricket_007 . I'm not too sure what you mean by that ?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot find the RecyclerView you speak of in Android Studio. Would you happen to have an example code of such a process ? @cricket_007

Comment: @cricket_007 I was searching for the view in the layout XML file. Thanks for your help. Is there a simpler way to go about achieving this ?

Comment: @cricket_007 
I have three rows and three strings. When the first string is added, it goes to row 1. When the second string is added, it goes to row 1 and the first string goes to row 2. When the third string is added, it goes to row 1, the second string goes to row 2 and the first string goes to row 3.

Comment: Ah. You only have three rows... That changes things. I would like to know what you've tried, though. Are you at least able to just add rows without reordering them?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/7280804/2308683

Comment: What I have coded so far: Enter text in Activity A, get text and place it in specific row in Activity B. (I have created 3 rows in the design XML file using TableLayout / TableRow) @cricket_007

Comment: @cricket_007  I now wish to: 

(1) reorder the rows in Activity B every time a new text is inputted in Activity A 

(2) save the state of the UI and row layout every time I go back to Activity A from Activity B (in order to input a new text)

Comment: You really should [edit] your question to include some layouts and code, then. It's hard to grasp what you are describing. Plus, like I said, going back and forth between activities doesn't play out so well with saving data

Comment: I used a shared preferences method, committing data to an editor and that seems to work in terms of saving data @cricket_007

Comment: Do you know how to reorder data in a table ? @cricket_007

Comment: I might. Still not seeing any  code in your question, though. Please provide a [mcve] of the problem

Comment: I just posted my code @cricket_007 . Disregard the recognizer part, I am using the pocketsphinx framework to add voice recognition to my app.

Comment: Are you only going to add a maximum of 3 rows?

Comment: For this project, yes I only require a maximum of 3 rows. 
Ideally in the future I would like more rows but that will come later. Will the number of rows make a considerable difference ? @Code-Apprentice

Comment: @Erz For a small, fixed number of rows TableLayout is probably sufficient. For many rows, you should use ListView or the newer RecyclerView instead.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thank you for your advice. I will be fine using TableLayout as I do not have many rows. Would you happen to know how to rearrange those rows and save the state of the UI when switching between activities ?

Comment: @Erz just change the text in each TextView. Not sure exactly what you need help with here.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I'm not sure if you read my original question, it is much more complicated than that. 
So far I have managed to code: inputting a string via voice command in Activity A and displaying it in an EditText field contained in a TableRow in Activity B. 
What I need help with: I wish to programmatically rearrange the TableRows so that every new string displayed in Activity B is displayed in row 1, pushing the other already displayed strings down one row. Then I wish to save the state of the TableRow arrangement every time I return to Activity A to input a new string by voice.

Comment: What views are in each row?

Comment: I have an EditText field in each row @Code-Apprentice

Answer (score 0):

Updated - Input activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static String PREFS_NAME = "prefs";
    public static String VALUES_KEY = "vals";

    EditText editText;
    SharedPreferences prefs;

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    private void addValue(Object s) {
        prefs.edit()
                .putString(VALUES_KEY, String.valueOf(s))
                .apply();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_edit_btn);

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String s = editText.getText().toString();
                JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();

                // Just for testing
                if (s.equals("clear")) {
                    addValue(arr);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "prefs cleared", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                String jsonString = prefs.getString(VALUES_KEY, arr.toString());

                // Store a JSON array
                try {
                    arr = new JSONArray(jsonString);
                    arr.put(s);
                    addValue(arr);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // Go to next activity
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, TableLayoutActivity.class));

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Second activity - Has the table

```
public class TableLayoutActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tablelayout);

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);

        TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);

        // Get the array out of preferences
        JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
        String jsonString = prefs.getString(MainActivity.VALUES_KEY, arr.toString());

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        try {
            arr = new JSONArray(jsonString);
            // Loop backwards over list, adding rows
            for (int i = arr.length() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
                View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.table_row, tl, false);
                TextView rowText = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

                rowText.setText( i + ": " + arr.getString(i));
                tl.addView(rowView,
                        TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Original Answer**

> every time I add a new string into the table, the previous string moves down one row and the new string takes the old string's place

I'm not seeing a TableLayout or TableRow in your question. There are three constant strings, but the order you want to display those in seems unclear.

But here's an approach... You store a List of Strings in SharedPreferences or database, whatever. You pass that list of strings to the Activity with the `TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout)`.

From there, you can simply loop backwards `for (int i = list.size(); i >=0; i--)`, get `String s = list.get(i);`, then generate a `TableRow tr = new TableRow()` which you'll add some `TextView` that you've `setText(s)` on it. (Or `inflate` some XML file containing both the `TextView` and `TableRow`).

When you are done building `TableRow tr`, then you can

```
tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
    TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
    TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Thereby, doing what I've quoted above.

Comment: Thank you for your response and advice, I shall try it out and see how I go. 
The TableLayout and EditText inside each TableRow were created in the XML file. They have the ID: diagnosis1, diagnosis2, and diagnosis3, but I realise now that it is the wrong way to go about it.

Comment: Would you also care to show me how to properly store a list of strings in SharedPreferences ? The method I used in my code unfortunately does not seem to work.

Comment: I'd probably use JSON representation. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27872280/2308683 Other solutions are in that post, though

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use JSON representation as my app has to function completely offline and cannot make use of external libraries. @cricket_007

Comment: JSON **is** offline. I think you are confusing yourself with REST APIs that use JSON to transfer data. You don't need to use external libraries either. `JsonArray` is a built-in Android class. Gson just makes it really easy to convert `List` objects to `JsonArray`, though, that's all

Comment: Ah I see, I apologise, as you can see I am not very experienced in programming.
Is there a way to use JsonArray without using Gson ? Or an easier SharedPreferences method for storing a list containing just 3 strings ?

Comment: Yeah, you make a `new JsonArray()`, then you call the `put()` method with a String value. Or... just use commas separated values `string1,string2,string3`, then you can `split(",")` to get a `String[]`. Either way, I think that post I linked discusses more than just the JSON option

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I will try it out and let you know if I run into any issues. @cricket_007

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. I have tried implementing your advice and unfortunately am unable to make it work as I am not very experienced. Do you mind typing up a more complete example of the code you mentioned above ? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate the effort. I will give it a go.