# Why is this not creating a new table?

Tags: java, android, object, tablelayout, layout-inflater

I have created a basic application to try and get this functionality working but I can't get this to work. When I click on the Add Table button it will create an instance of the layout file which includes a table layout and 3 table rows. I've got this far from just combining a bunch of answers to questions I've seen on here but I'm struggling to get this to work.

It creates two tables if I click on add table and so on if I keep clicking it. However the name is only changing for the first table like so:

Before:

[image: Before]

After:

[image: After]

So table 1 should say "tableLayout0" and table 2 should say "tableLayout1". On each button click I want it to create a completely new table which just has the same layout properties.

```
int i;
Button addBtn;
LinearLayout linearLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    i = 0;
    linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    addBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addBtn);

    addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            createTable();
            i++;
        }
    });
}

public void createTable(){

    String tableLayoutName = "tableLayout"+i;

     TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(this);

     View tableCell = this.getLayoutInflater()
            .inflate(R.layout.table_details, null, false);

    tableLayout.addView(tableCell);
    linearLayout.addView(tableLayout);

    Button addSetBtn;
    addSetBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addSetBtn);
    addSetBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            toastMessage("Click Registered");
        }
    });

    TextView exerciseNameTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.exerciseNameTextView);
    exerciseNameTextView.setText(tableLayoutName);

}

//Adaptable Toast Message
private void toastMessage(String message){
    Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: You are not giving layout parameters to table layout when setting it in linear layout. Try to give it LinearLayouy.LayoutParams

Comment: I just quickly searched and this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279501/programmatically-adding-tablerow-to-tablelayout-not-working

Comment: It didn't work. Added: 

linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT), LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        
Tried doing the same to the tableCell view variable too:


tableCell.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams((TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT), TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

Took out the tableLayout also as just realised that I didn't need it as the xml file already has one so tableCell goes straight into the linearLayout. Still having the same issue however.

Comment: Call `findViewById(R.id.exerciseNameTextView)` on `tableCell` to get the `TextView` for the current one. As you have it now, it's just finding the first one with that ID in the `Activity`'s whole layout, which will always be the first one you added. Also, the `TableLayout`s you're wrapping those cells in seem completely unnecessary, as they each only have one child. Can't you just add `tableCell` directly to `linearLayout`?

Comment: Ahhhh yes that's fixed it! Thank you! I changed this for the button click also and it works. Yeah I noticed that the extra TableLayout was pointless after I put in the first suggestion. That's what I have it set too now.

Comment: Oh, yeah, whoops. I glossed right over the `Button`.