# how to to add increase and decrease table layout row index list values in android studio

Tags: java, android

```
static int index = 5;
Button nextButton, backbutton;
TableLayout tableLayout;
int i, preval,preival;
int nexval  ;
String[] arr = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R"};
nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                //TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablenew);
                for (int j= 0; j < arr.length ; j++)
                {
                    Log.e("nextindex", String.valueOf(j));
                    TableRow row = (TableRow) tableLayout.getChildAt(j);
                    Integer id = ((Integer) row.getTag());

                    if (id > index && id <= (index + 5))
                    {
                        row.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        preval=j;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        row.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
                preival=index;
                preival=preival-5;
                index = index + 5;
            }
        });
        backbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // tableLayout.removeView(tableRow);

                for (int k = preval; k > preival; k--) {

                    Log.e("backindex", String.valueOf(k));
                    TableRow row = (TableRow) tableLayout.getChildAt(k);
                    Integer id = ((Integer) row.getTag());

                    if (id < index && id <= (index - 5)) {
                        row.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        nexval = k;
                    } else {
                        row.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
                preival = preival - 5;
                index = index - 5;

            }

        });
```

Comment: Please read this. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
Format your code and include a question. It should not be all code.

Answer (score 0):

Please better format you code. For adding a new row use this code:

```
TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.mytableid);
TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Check this article [Programmatically adding TableRow to TableLayout not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279501/programmatically-adding-tablerow-to-tablelayout-not-working)