# Add TableRow dynamically to linearlayout android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, tablerow

I need to dynamically add some tablerows to a linearlayout in my app. I write this code:

```
LinearLayout tabella = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabella_contatori);

    for(int i =0; i<array_list.size(); i++){
        TableRow row = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
        row.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        TextView data = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        data.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.2f));
        data.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), android.R.attr.textAppearanceMedium);
        data.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        data.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        data.setPadding(2, 0, 0, 0);
        data.setText("asd");

        row.addView(data);
        tabella.addView(row);
    }
}
```

But when I open the app nothing appens. I already check if array_list.size is bigger than 0.
How can I do?
Thanks, Mattia

Comment: you usually add tablerows to tablelayouts

Comment: Where in your app do you do this?  onCreate?  Maybe a button click?

Comment: I need to do it without oncreate, without clicking on a button

Comment: how you can add Table Rows to Linear Layout it should be in Table Layout.

Comment: In xml file R.id.tabella_contatori is a tablelayout, but in java code i set it as linealayout, i don't know why.. i set it to tablelayout but it still doesn't working

Comment: I found the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200691/dynamically-add-tablerow-to-tablelayout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in your TextView Layout Params. The type should be TableRow.LayoutParams not LinearLayout.LayoutParams.
`data.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));`

Answer (score 1):

Take Table layout and try using this in your main.xml ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myTableLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
     <TableRow
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">

          <TextView android:text="Some Text"/>

     </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

in your Activity

```
this.setContentView(R.layout.main);

/* Find Tablelayout defined in main.xml */
TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.myTableLayout);
     /* Create a new row to be added. */
     TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
     tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
          /* Create a TextView to be the row-content. */    

        TextView data = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        data.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.2f));
        data.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), android.R.attr.textAppearanceMedium);
        data.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        data.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        data.setPadding(2, 0, 0, 0);
        data.setText("asd");

          /* Add TextView to row. */
          tr.addView(data);
    /* Add row to TableLayout. */
    tl.addView(tr,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
          LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
          LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```