# How to set button width dynamically at runtime to fill the screen?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am learning android development and I am trying to fill the screen with six buttons. But I want to set the button size dynamically. I am getting screen size using

```
final DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
final int screenWidthInDp = (int) (displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density);
```

and I am trying to set the handlers of each button using

```
button.setWidth(screenWidthInDp/6);
```

I have six buttons in each row and I want the size change depending on the screen and the six buttons to fill the screen. Am I doing something wrong?

This is what a button looks like in my activity.xml

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/bNum10"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bNum2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bNum0"
    android:text="@string/sign" />
```

This is my layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Calc" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Display"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="25sp"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/Welcome"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bNum2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/bNum1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bNum1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bNum1"
        android:text="@string/two" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bNum3"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/bNum2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bNum2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bNum2"
        android:text="@string/three" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bNum5"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bNum4"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bNum4"
        android:text="@string/five" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bNum6"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/bNum5"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bNum5"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bNum5"
        android:text="@string/six" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bNum0"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Display"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:text="@string/zero" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bNum1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bNum0"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/bNum0"
        android:text="@string/one" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bNum4"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bNum1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/bNum1"
        android:text="@string/four" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bNum7"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bNum5"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/seven" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bNum8"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bNum5"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bNum6"
        android:text="@string/eight" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bNum9"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bNum8"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/bNum6"
        android:text="@string/nine" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bNum10"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bNum2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bNum0"
        android:text="@string/sign" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bEqual"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/bExp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bExp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/equal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bDot"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/bNum10"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bNum10"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bNum10"
        android:text="@string/dot" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bExp"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/bDot"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bDot"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bDot"
        android:text="@string/exp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use linearlayout and weight to display 6 buttons with equal width.

```
<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal" android:weightSum="6" >

     <Button

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

     <Button
                   android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_weight="1" />
  <Button
                       android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_weight="1" />
  <Button
                       android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_weight="1" />
  <Button
                       android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_weight="1" />
  <Button
                       android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_weight="1" />


  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: May you please elaborate more on how I do that? I have 6 buttons per row not total. My bad for that. I want each row to be filled

Comment: set width of all the buttons to 0dp and weight to 1. Also set the weightSum of the linearlayout to 6. Let rest of the properties as you wanted(id, text etc.)

Comment: Wait wait. I also have a textView inside the layout, I do not want that to be altered. also, what do you mean by let rest? (my english is not perfect)

Comment: post your layout as well

Comment: you have more than 6 buttons in layout. what is expected layout can you draw it??? which 6 button you want to be in a row?

Comment: Well it is going to be different rows of six buttons in each. I just want to know how to do it in general and I will try to apply it in my work

Comment: Try with Linear Layout. Every 6 buttons in one Linear Layout.

Comment: @MSI What do you mean precisely. I apologise if it is too simple for you guys but I am trying to teach myself android not just do something and I want to learn how and why I am doing each thing

Comment: @vipulmittal I am rereading your solution and trying to understand it. You are suggesting that I include a new layout for each row inside my layout and the rest (which I understood) or the layout you are suggesting is the total layout? because What I want is six buttons in each row and on the top row a textview. Which of the two ways should I use?

Comment: 1st point. Introduce a LinearLayout for each row and put 6 button in it. So in your relative layout you will have one TextView and LinearLayout for each row having 6 buttons

Answer (score 0):

@vipul mittal has the answer if you do not need to set it programmatically. However, since you asked "what am I doing wrong" also, you do not set Button widths using dp - it's pixels.

So, when you get the display metrics just divide the pixels by 6 like this:

```
button.setWidth((int) (displayMetrics.widthPixels/6));
```

Comment: aren't we supposed to do it with dp? that is what I read in android tutorials. I am a noob though

Comment: in XML, yes. But programmatically, the Button widget is done in pixels: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setWidth(int)

Comment: Tried it, it makes no difference. Either I do with dp or actual pixels it does not work

Comment: I didn't check your layout, but looking closer you have margin in your parent layout and the buttons don't really line up. You need to subtract for the margin and possibly add space between them.

Comment: I have on two buttons that are off yes. But that is not the issue here. I am looking for a way to make them programmatically fill a row

Comment: post a pic or something of the problem. I mean to say that displayMetrics is the entire width of the screen, but the parent layout for your buttons is taking up some space - they won't line up proper

Answer (score 0):

Using Linear Layout will best option in the XML. Like this:

```
<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal" 
     android:weightSum="1" >

     <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.15" />

     <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.15" />

       // Other buttons and texview in similar way. Total sum of android:layout_weight values need to be 1.
  </LinearLayout>
```

It seems you are more interested to do it in TableLayout and 6 buttons and 1 TextView in each row. I would you do change things in xml in this way:

```
<TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:shrinkColumns="*"
            android:stretchColumns="*" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_span="3" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_span="3" />

                    // Other buttons and texview in similar way

            </TableRow>
```

Comment: There is only one textview, it's six buttons per row, don't have the current number of buttons now, I will add more

Comment: So you don't know how many buttons there will be in each row?

Comment: It's six buttons per row, the number of rows I do not know.

Comment: In that case you should try to use a ListView and add the Layout of one row inside of the ListView

Comment: Or Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200691/dynamically-add-tablerow-to-tablelayout