# How to customize UI size elements in android

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

Okay, so right now the only way I know how to size buttons in android without majorly screwing it up is 'wrap_content' and 'match_parent'.  What if I want to customize it to screen size.  Here's what I mean:
In Iphone developing you can request the screensize and then divide the number of pixels you want by screen size to make something proportional to screen size.  How do you do this in android.  Also how do you move something from java to xml. for instance if i do

```
    int x;
    4/2=x
```

how do i write x to my xml file as a resource.  Sorry for the noob post and thanks!

Comment: You should look into layout weight -- it allows you to specify a relative 'weight' for an element proportional to the other elements in the layout.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558345/how-to-set-button-width-dynamically-at-runtime-to-fill-the-screen/21558403#21558403

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to take a look at `android:layout_weight`, which allows you to abstract the specific devices' screens and it will scale appropriately. See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html) for more info and some examples.

From the link above (the android docs):

> `LinearLayout` also supports assigning a *weight* to individual children with the `android:layout_weight` attribute. This attribute assigns an "importance" value to a view in terms of how much space is should occupy on the screen. A larger weight value allows it to expand to fill any remaining space in the parent view. Child views can specify a weight value, and then any remaining space in the view group is assigned to children in the proportion of their declared weight. Default weight is zero.
>
> For example, if there are three text fields and two of them declare a weight of 1, while the other is given no weight, the third text field without weight will not grow and will only occupy the area required by its content. The other two will expand equally to fill the space remaining after all three fields are measured. If the third field is then given a weight of 2 (instead of 0), then it is now declared more important than both the others, so it gets half the total remaining space, while the first two share the rest equally.

Comment: I also got downvoted, but no explanation. Provide more information if this isn't helpful.

Answer (score -1):

For use as per the screen size u can use weight sum for viewgroup i.e LinearLayout or Tablelayout. and now u can use full screen width with proper button size.

You can create your own views where u can define your own tag with some values. for custom view [follow the link](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html)