# Programatically added layout elements dissapper when I quit the activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

What I want to do is to create new TableRows on a TableLayout via the `onClick` method of a Button. I used the code of a relevant question on stackoverflow: [Dynamically add TableRow to TableLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200691/dynamically-add-tablerow-to-tablelayout). However, TableRows disappear when I proceed to another Activity or quit the app.

How can I make this change permanent? And furthermore, how can I remove them conditionally, i.e. after 50 seconds passed?

Comment: Please provide the  relevant portions of your code, otherwise it will be impossible to help. 
Also try to improve the formatting of your question, so people trying to help you can quickly see what your question is about.

Answer (score -1):

```
TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.spreadsheet);
TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
```

- You've followed above sample code. Take these variable tl, tr as class variables (Your activity member variables).

Comment: I want to consider adding arbitrary number of table rows, i.e. whenever user clicks the button. I guess it would require lots of class variable which may not be sufficient.